# Setting up a custom nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I'm trying to setup my own nameservers for my server. So far I have:

1. Installed **bind9** via `apt-get`
2. Updated my DNS so I have:

   NS1.NEWBYHOST.COM => 213.219.38.44 (and also an AAAA record)

   NS2.NEWBYHOST.COM => 213.219.38.44 (and also an AAAA record)
3. It has now updated, and pings correctly:

> PS C:\Users\Andy> ping NS1.NEWBYHOST.COM
>
> Pinging NS1.NEWBYHOST.COM [213.219.38.44] with 32 bytes of data: Reply
>   from 213.219.38.44: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54 Reply from
>   213.219.38.44: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54
>
> Ping statistics for 213.219.38.44:
>       Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 10ms Control-C PS C:\Users\Andy> ping NS2.NEWBYHOST.COM
>
> Pinging NS2.NEWBYHOST.COM [213.219.38.44] with 32 bytes of data: Reply
>   from 213.219.38.44: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54 Reply from
>   213.219.38.44: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=54
>
> Ping statistics for 213.219.38.44:
>       Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 10ms

However, when trying to update my domain in GoDaddy, I get an error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly godaddy are checking there, but does the relevant zone exist on your nameserver?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist thanks for the quick reply. What do you mean by the "relevant zone" ?

Comment: The domain name that you are delegating should exist as a zone on your nameserver.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist - you mean on the Linode DNS? (newbyhost.com is pointing there, and then I have the ns1 and ns2 pointing to the new server where the DNS server is hosted).

Comment: here is what I have: https://ibb.co/matohn

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist is this what you mean? https://ibb.co/j3vC8S (I just added the last 2 entries)

Comment: Which zone are you trying to delegate, `newbyhost.com` or something else?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist - newbyhost.com is on linodes DNS (and will stay there, as the host). Then ns1.newbyhost.com and ns2.newbyhost.com need to point to my server (213.219.38.44), where I have the bind service running

Comment: I just did a test on http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/domain_check, and get: "A search was performed starting with the root servers, but no NS records were found for this domain. ". So hopefully I just need to wait for the DNS on linode to update with the new NS records I added?

Comment: For your specific error: if you are trying to use these nameservers, you first need to register them at the relevant registry, through the registrar of `newbyhost.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with what you are trying to do here. The `Unavailable` error you get is simply a measure to prevent you from doing such errors. Your configuration doesn't meet the IANA [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements):

1. You only have one name server `213.219.38.44`. This has two problems, of which the second is a logical cause from the first. Even if your single server has two different IP addresses, it still wouldn't fully meet the purpose of the *network diversity* requirement. Also, you don't actually want the whole domain to simply disappear every time your single server is down, do you?

   > **Minimum number of name servers**
   >
   > There must be at least two NS records listed in a delegation, and the
   >   hosts must not resolve to the same IP address.
   >
   > **Network diversity**
   >
   > The name servers must be in at least two topologically separate networks. A network is defined as an origin autonomous system in the BGP routing table. The requirement is assessed through inspection of views of the BGP routing table.
2. Your single name server isn't configured to answer authoritatively for `newbyhost.com`:

   ```
   dig newbyhost.com @213.219.38.44

   ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> newbyhost.com @213.219.38.44
   ;; global options: +cmd
   ;; Got answer:
   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 56269
   ;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
   ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
   ```

   If you just installed Bind 9, you'd need to configure it, too!

   > **Answer authoritatively**
   >
   > The name servers must answer authoritatively
   >   for the designated zone. Responses to queries to the name servers for
   >   the designated zone must have the “AA”-bit set.
   >
   > This will be tested by querying for the SOA record of the designated
   >   zone with no “RD”-bit set.
3. If you use the domain itself for its name servers, you should have *glue records* at the parent.

If you are trying to have own name servers for vanity reasons alone, stop right there: Linode has the expertise to host the name servers for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused as to how you would run 2 DNS servers with the same data? My DNS records on 213.219.38.44
 are created using our GUI system (VestaCP). It enters the correct records into the system. Can't we just use 2 different IPs, but the same server? I know its not ideal - but seeing as the only sites that are going to be served from this DNS server, are the sites that are on it - its kind of irrelevant if it is on another server (as the site would be down either way). Does that make sense?

Comment: BTW, I'm not just doing this for vanity reasons :) I'm trying to get SpamAssasins spam checks to work (its telling me I've gone over my limit, which apparently is due to  the fact we are using the shared Linode  nameservers, which get overloaded with all the traffic coming through from their servers

Comment: Also, I guess one workaround would be to just setup 1 NS on my server, and then leave the 2nd one as Linodes? Its not ideal as it means I would need to keep both in sync - but it would mean I could have a fallback DNS (again, kinda pointless as the nameserver and websites are on the same server)

Comment: Guess what? There is a technology for keeping the records up to date on every single secondary name server! It's called _DNS Zone Transfer_ ([RFC 5936](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5936)): the secondary name servers are configured to copy the zone from the master whenever it's updated.

Comment: thanks, will check into that. I have quite a few servers, so I guess I could piggy-back them off each other (thus giving the extra IP's needed and servers).

Comment: @AndrewNewby I do not understand your explanation about doing all of that because of SpamAssassing checks and Linode nameservers. I advise you to dig more into this as I am pretty sure setting your own nameservers will not help you; specifically because you are learning to do it, so if really needed (which I doubt) you should start with small simple cases not in production before growing bigger/more complex.

Comment: You are also probably mixing authoritative and recursive nameservers. The way you speak about Linode nameservers seems to me that you are speaking about their recursive nameservers, used by servers hey host. This has nothing to do with authoritative nameservers providing data for some domains, which is what you are attempting to do. So again I urge you to revisit to whole issue to really understand the core of the problem with SpamAssassin before going the route of setting up authoritative nameservers on which a domain will depend.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks. Yes, I would much prefer to only use Linodes DNS as its one less fail point in our system. https://goo.gl/VcT5Qh (see 2nd post), and another https://goo.gl/t5qAKG . Basically the problem seems to be we are sharing Linode's DNS server IPs, and that is why they are blocking us from using the URIBL feature

Comment: @Andrew see the relevant link for this data: "Resolving the block might be as simple as using your own non-forwarding caching nameserver to avoid being lumped together with other users queries;" This means you need to install a recursive nameserver not an authoritative one like you were trying to do. Install `unbound` for example, or `bind` (but more complicated) and configure it to be only available for your own servers and make  sure they use it (change every `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to your newly installed nameserver.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks. I will look into that. Would certainly be much better for what I need. I remember reading something about not editing the resolv.conf file myself as it gets overwritten, so will need to look into a way around that. I just found this: https://goo.gl/DYQyd8

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thanks a ton - that was so much easier! 1) Install `unbound` 2) Edit /etc/resolve.conf to only use `127.0.0.1` 3) Disable auto network updating on Linode (otherwise it overwrites resolv.conf). ...reboot the server, and voila... it checks the domains in emails now. WAHOOO! :) Thanks